# Extract data (string, char, etc.) from an incoming stream on a C socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp, esp8266

How do I extract the actual data (in a form of human readable string, character, an integer etc.) from an incoming stream on a socket in C? The point of this is to be able to act on the contents of the incoming message.

```
struct netconn *client = NULL;
struct netconn *nc = netconn_new(NETCONN_TCP);
netconn_bind(nc, IP_ADDR_ANY, 8569);
netconn_listen(nc);

while (1) {
    err_t err = netconn_accept(nc, &client);
    if (err == ERR_OK) {
        struct netbuf *nb;
        if ((err = netconn_recv(client, &nb)) == ERR_OK) {

            /* INTERPRETE INCOMING DATA HERE?? */

        }
        netbuf_delete(nb);
    }
    netconn_close(client);
    netconn_delete(client);
}
```

The client connects and sends, say 'testing123' string. How do I go about interpreting this string on the 'server' side?

The point of this exercise is to be able to trigger desired behaviour on the receiving end with the use of appropriate 'command' sent across the local network to WLAN-attached ESP8266 microcontroller.

Ps. I realize it's probably very primitive mechanism so I would appreciate some feedback regarding this matter. Any thoughts/ideas/suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*How do I go about interpreting this string on the 'server' side?*" this depends on the "language" client and server agreed to "speak". We do not know this "language".

Comment: `testing123` for example could be taken as `test` and `ing123`, or as `testing` and `123` or as ... or even as incomplete.

Comment: I communicate with it through the python interface by sending encoded string as in: 'msg = "testing123" s.send(msg.encode())', didn't think it would matter, a string is a string to me, obviously I know very little about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivial excercise as it turns out. The `netbuf` structure have 'placeholders' for the contents of incoming data and it's lenght;

`netbuf_data(nb, &data, &len);`

In my case;

```
/* INTERPRETE INCOMING DATA HERE?? */

void *data;
u16_t len;
netbuf_data(nb, &data, &len);

char * theData = data;
printf("%s\n", theData);
```

prints the incoming string on-screen.

Answer (score 0):

As your server can't know what and how the data is being send you need to specify a common message or some kind of seperator between words if you choose to use strings.

For example you could use a `|` as a seperator so that you would input the following on your client: `testing|123`

On your server you would now need to search for the `|` seperator and divide the incoming data so you have a string "testing" and a int "123".

As another aproach you could define yourself a interface based on numbers with the help of a struct.
For example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int cmd;
    int subCmd;
} cmdStruct;
```

In this you would need to deserialize the incoming bytes and parse them to the command structure and act upon the received command. This would include that you send the command accordingly.